# Wordpress: first post on loop when paged does not show

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two loops running on my front-page: The first pulls the 'Featured' category and returns one post. Then my main loop below it pulls all other posts.

I have it set so the featured area doesn't show on the pages 2+. However, on pages 2+ the main posts are being offset by [1], does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is my code: front-page.php

```
<?php get_template_part('featured'); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<div class="main top-zero-margin">
    <div class="outer-hold">
        <div class="marge">
            <h3 class="front-page-title">The Latest</h3>
        <?php 
        if (have_posts()) :
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if ( in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) continue; ?>
 <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php endwhile;
        else :
            echo "<p>No content found</p>";
        endif; ?>
```

Featured.php

```
<div class="featured-area">
   <?php $featuredPosts = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&cat=26');
   if (is_front_page() && !is_paged()) { ?> <?php 

     if ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) while ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
     <?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) { 

        the_post_thumbnail(); }
    else {
    echo 
    '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/absent-featured.png" />'
    ; } ?>
        <h1>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h1>

        <!-- begin author -->

        <p>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
        </a>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php 
} else { echo '';} ?>
</div><!-- end featured-area -->
```